# Two programming programs suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-8, command-line, eclipse, android

I use eclipse and the android SDK to code, and suddenly both of them stopped working. I posted this on Stack Overflow, and nobody came up with an answer that worked. It seems that it may be more of a problem with my computer and not with the actual programs. Here's a description of the problem.

Whenever I start the program from my start menu or desktop, the loading screen pops up for about a second, then disappears. I tried to run it from command prompt, and the same thing happened. The loading screen popped up for a second, then disappeared. No errors came up. Then I tried to run it adding -clean in command prompt, and the same thing happened.

The only difference on my computer is that I recently installed the Leap Motion software and SDK.

I have uninstalled the Leap Motion software, and uninstalled, then re-installed eclipse and the android SDK 3 times already.

No errors come up when it from command prompt.

I'm running windows 8 on a Samsung tablet PC. I've never had any problems before.

---

NOTE

---

This is not a programming question, it is a question about my computer having a problem running a program that has been working for 4 months now

I did not know about the migration function when I posted here, so here is a link to my original question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137455/eclipse-and-android-sdk-stopped-working

---

SOLVED

---

I re-installed java, and now it works perfectly! I think I may have messed up Java when I stopped an update in progress (which I forgot about until this morning. Sorry) Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: If you want to move a question to a different site in the Stack Exchange network, you should use the "flag" link below it to flag the question for moderator attention and request migration (and specify to where). That said, I somewhat fail to see what you expect from posting it here (where the audience is basically general computer users) when posting it in a more specialized place (StackOverflow being inhabited mostly by people involved with software development) did not yield anything useful. *At the very least*, you should link to the question on SO so we can see what came up there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that I could flag it and ask for a migration, and I figured because I have seen a few questions of programs not working correctly, This site may be able to help more. It seems to be a problem more with my computer, because there are no errors coming up when I launch it. I will however, explore different Stack Exchange sites to see if there is a different one better suited for my needs.

Comment: We're all new here at one time, but do keep in mind that generally, cross-posting a question to multiple Stack Exchange sites is heavily frowned upon. It's better to try to find the one which is geared toward whatever your question is about; look in the Help Center to find out what the subject of each site is, and if you are uncertain, head on over to the site's Meta (both are linked to in the top bar) and ask there before posting.

Comment: Thank you for this information, and I will keep that in mind for next time. I had originally posted on Stack Overflow, because I had thought it was a problem with the multiple programs on my computer. I then posted here, because I then learned it may be a problem with my actual computer itself. I believe this site is better suited for my question. The description of Super User is computer enthusiasts, and I thought that somebody may have had a similar problem on their computer. This is not a programming question, it is a question about a problem with my computer running a program.

Comment: Usually enlightenment arises when you run the eclipse startup command from a cmd window.

Comment: It could be that installing the Leap Motion software has updated some component that Eclipse uses, but Eclipse does not like the new version. For example, Leap Motion could have updated Java to a version that Eclipse does not like.

Comment: @sgmoore, wouldn't there have been an error when i ran it through command prompt if that had happened?

Comment: In the ideal world yes, but unfortunately life isn't always like that. Sometimes (we) programmers make assumptions and forget to check our assumptions, or forget to check return codes or write error messages to log files/event log rather than displaying them to the user. For example, I was trying to upgrade my Windows 7 computer to Windows 8 and after an hour or so, it ended up rebooting back into Windows 7. The actual error (which caused the install to abort and put everything back the way it was) was hidden away in a log file which had thousands of lines of information/warnings/errors etc.

Comment: Other suggestions: scan your disk for defects. Look in the event logs.

Comment: The problem is, i had installed the leap motion software on my windows 7 computer, and eclipse still works fine on there

Comment: How were you launching it from the command line?  Point to the java.exe (do not use javaw.exe when troubleshooting) with the -vm switch and see what happens and what the logs say.  Where did you install Eclipse?  Could the ownership or access permissions for you have been changed?  Could they have been changed on your installed copy of Java?